# How can i make it so the overflow of a div positions to the right ? CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok so this is how it looks right now but i want to overflow to go to the right instead of down.

[image: The site]

This is the CSS code:

```
body{
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    background-image:url('../images/background.png');
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#logo{
    font-size:45px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#today_section{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:900px;
    height:219px;
    background-image:url("../images/slider_background.png");
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.movie{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    width:134px;
    height:199px;
}
```

The slider is called "today_section" and each movie has the class "movie".

Comment: According to ma gues the width of your `#today_section` should be increased to maximum to fix this issue.

Comment: looks like a carousel to me/

Comment: Yep it is a carrousel :) Andrew, in fact you set a `width : 900px` which allow your 5 firsts movie to be displayed inline. You should consider increasing this value in order to let the div float left.

Comment: thanks :) it worked I increased the width and added overflow hidden to the container

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#today_section{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.movie{
    display:inline-block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.movie{
   float:left;
}
```

try adding this

Answer (score 0):

I raised the width of the today_section to 2000 and added overflow:hidden to the container